# How to use special characters in username/password for HTTP proxy?

Tags: windows, special-characters, http-proxy

I am trying to setup an HTTP proxy on a Windows machine. Problem is, the password has a special character (@) in it that is causing the `set` command to fail.

I have tried both escaping the character (`\@`) and percent-encoding it with the hex value (`%40`), to no avail.

For example, with the username Foo and password B@r, I have tried the following commands:

```
set http_proxy=http://foo:B\@r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
set http_proxy=http://foo:B%40r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

Other than changing the password how can I have the proxy use the password?

Comment: Is the set failing or is the tool using the http_proxy environment variable failing due to the @ symbol?

Comment: Yes. Because the format is username:password@server:port, having @ in the middle of your password causes the right hand side of your password to be considered the hostname, thus the hostname resolution above fails because it thinks the hostname is r@http-gateway.domain.org. The "r@" should not be there.

Comment: I tried using %40 and it worked (on Windows), are you sure?

Comment: In fact, it works on both Windows and Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password

Answer (score 50):

You have to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) | [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters. E.g. instead of this:

```
http://foo:B@r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

you write this:

```
http://foo:B%40r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

So `@` gets replaced with `%40`.

Note:  foo = username, b@r = password, http-gateway.domain.org = host proxy to connect

Comment: encoding is indeed the way to get around this problem (and many others).

Comment: i found that i needed to double urlencode some characters

Comment: I suggest simply using javascript `encodeURIComponent()` to this purpose. You can easily use your browser's `DeveloperTools -> Console`.

Answer (score 3):

For any special characters, in username or password, we can always use UTF-8 encoded strings in its place.
For example: ! can be replaced with %21

so the command would be, if password is abc!:

npm config set proxy http://user:abc%21@proxy.world.com:8080/

npm config set https-proxy http://user:abc%21@proxy.world.com:8080/

Answer (score 2):

Use %Ascii code of the special character in hexadecimal notation for any special character. Suppose My password is ***AB@12#&*** then the password should be set as

`git config --global http.proxy *http://usernamne:**AB%4012%23%26**@myipadress:portnumber*`

Refer to ascii table for knowing the hexadecimal ascii code of any number.

Answer (score -1):

Based upon this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667878/why-do-windows-environment-variable-names-use-a-special-escape-character), can you try using ^ to escape the @ symbol?

Comment: In response to both, the set is successful, it is the tool using the environment variable:
`set http_proxy=http://foo:B^@r@http-gateway.domain.org:80`
`jruby -S gem install rake`
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
the scheme http does not accept registry part: foo:B@r@http-gateway.domain.org:80 (or bad hostname?)

Comment: This is a Linux based question, not a Windows based question, using ^ doesn't work for me. I still get `wget: unable to resolve host address `tf4ce@server.company.com'` after setting the proxy environmental variable.

Comment: Actually it IS a Windows based question...I know pyropenguin personally.